# Designing your own Algorithm

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, keys, stream-cipher

I have been told to design my own algorithm as a college assignment.  What I could have come up with was a random cipher.  For example:

Suppose my plaintext is: `AND`

So I'll take an array the size of my plaintext and keep on storing random values between 0 to 9.

I will use random values and my array becomes `{3,5,1}`

My encrypted text becomes `DSE`

I have used a random function for generating random values.

Is this encryption algorithm good enough? Moreover, how can someone break it? Is it vulnerable in any way? If someone else can guide me in making a good original encryption algorithm, that would be great.

Comment: "I have been told to design my own Algorithm as my college assignment" - you've been asked to create a homebrew encryption algorithm (or did they just say 'algorithm', and you decided to do encryption, rather than, say, sorting).  I can't see what you'd be expected to learn from creating a homebrew encryption algorithm, unless the next step would be to find ways to break it...

Comment: @poncho  Is this how we welcome new entrants into cryptography? I'm upvoting.

Comment: @PaulUszak: if someone wants to learn about cryptography, designing your own cipher is not the right way to do it.

Comment: @PaulUszak: in any case, my amazement was him being assigned that in college, more than a criticism of anything he did...

Comment: This seems to be really, really bad - from the college course, requesting such an assignment. If someone comes up with $AES(x) \oplus 0...01$, how would they break it afterwards? If the assignment was this unspecific, this might be awful to the students with the right intuition of cryptography.

Comment: @poncho: completely agree with you... I find it completely pointless of my college course to ask such thing in first place considering that we are new to cryptography... Just my learning some basic encryption algorithms, we don't become able enough to design our own... There's still a lot for me to learn from existing techniques